# Dirichlet-Multinomial Distribution with many zero counts

Tags: zero-inflation, dirichlet-distribution, dirichlet-process

**Short version**: Is there someway to make the dirchlet-multinomial distribution sensitive to the presence of zero counts?

---

**Long version**:

I am attempting model metric positions in musical data.

You can think of the data as a series of numbers representing the number of beats ("offsets") since the beginning of the piece. An example piece (call it Piece A) might look like this:

0 1 2 4 5 6 8 10 12 13 14

In order to model (duple) meter, I can simply take modulo 8 on these values, getting:

0 1 2 4 5 6 0 2 4 5 6

I can look at the distribution of these metric (modulo 8) positions, and model them as a multinomial distribution. For this piece the distribution looks like:

**Position** = *Count*:

**0** = *2*, **1** = *1*, **2** = *2*, **3** = *0*, **4** = *2*, **5** = *2*, **6** = *2*, **7** = *0*

I have 200 pieces, and I'm sure that metric positions within pieces are dependent, thus it makes sense to estimate a dirichlet-multinomial distribution across the 200 pieces, rather than a simple multinomial distribution.

---

Here is where it gets complicated: my 200 pieces vary enormously in terms of tempo. As a result (and since the same traditional "note values" are used to notate these pieces), another piece (Piece B) in the corpus might look like this:

0 2 4 8 10 12 16 20 24 26 28

and Modulo 8:

0 2 4 0 2 4 0 4 0 2 4

Notice, that this is essentially the same rhythm as the other piece, but the duration values are doubled, so the distribution of metric positions (modulo 8) looks quite different:

**0** = *4*, **1** = *0*, **2** = *3*, **3** = *0*, **4** = *4*, **5** = *0*, **6** = *0*, **7** = *0*

---

What I'd like to is add another 200 parameters as scaling parameters ($n$) for each piece, such that the beat offset values in each piece are multiplied by  $2^n$. Thus, for Piece B above, the rhythmic values might be multiplied by $2^{-1}$, so that the rhythm, and the distribution of metric positions, becomes the same as Piece A.

The model would estimate the 8-parameters ($\alpha$) for the dirichlet-multinomial distribution (representing the "global" distribution of metric positions) and simultaneously estimate a scaling parameter for each piece.

The problem is that if a high-scaling parameter is selected for a piece, the distribution of metric positions ends up with zeros in most positions, *and the dirichlet-multinomial distribution essentially ignores zeros*, resulting in a higher likelihood estimate.

Is there someway to make the dirchlet-multinomial distribution sensitive to the presence of zero counts?